# Convert number 10 to 0.10 float

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add decimal to my number, but when I use toFixed(function), it adds ".00", but instead this, I'd like to do: 10 to 0.10 or 1234 to 12,34. Is there any function that does this?

Comment: divide your number by 100 ...

Comment: What's wrong with dividing it by 100?

Comment: just x/100 ? otherwise you can see number_format http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/

Comment: what do you mean by float?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm kind of hoping it's not this simple...

```
var num = 10;
var dec = num/100;
```

For educations sake though, let's do it a bit better:

```
var dec = (num/100).toFixed(2);
```

`.toFixed(x)` will force the number into a format with x amount of decimal places. This will be useful in cases that `num` is greater than 100 but you still want the .00 added.

Or, in the case of `num` being a string:

```
var dec = ((parseFloat(num)/100).toFixed(2);
```

`parseFloat` will convert a string to a number. Possibly not needed depending on where `num` is coming from for you, but useful to know how to do regardless.

Comment: Bear in mind that the incoming number may not always be an integer, so it might be worth using `parseFloat(num)` in place of `parseInt(num)`. And remember to use the radix (the number base, so `parseInt(num, 10)`) if only for safety's sake.

Comment: parseInt(num, 10) => sometimes the default base is base 16

Comment: Good tips guys, changed code to `parseFloat`. Also a little amusing that once of my best answers is... divide by 100 :(

Answer (score 0):

See [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) to give your number standard comma format.

```js
var number = 3500;

alert(number.toLocaleString());
```

Divide you number to '100' to get floating point.